# Python: Update list parameters

Tags: python

For string we can have

```
msg = 'successfully returned with msg: %s'
msg %= "Elegant";
```

Can we do the same for list,

For instance ,

```
cmd = [
    "Message %s",
    "Param %s"
    ]

cmd %= (msg, param)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zip()` to pair the two lists in a new [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> cmd = [
...     "Message %s",
...     "Param %s"
...     ]
>>> msg = "foo"
>>> param = "bar"
>>> newcmd = [item % par for item,par in zip(cmd, (msg,param))]
>>> newcmd
['Message foo', 'Param bar']
```

Comment: But it will update cmd. Cant we keep cmd unchanged ?. I want to run it in a for loop and msg and param will change for every iteration

Comment: @Pilot: Just assign the result to a different variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension with `zip()`:

```
cmd = [s % (value,) for s, value in zip(cmd, (msg, param))]
```

to apply the various values to list elements individually.

This produces a new list; assign back to `cmd`, or a different name, take your pick.

Comment: That results in a `TypeError`. You need `zip()` in order to correctly pair the two lists/tuples.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: ah, missed that indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like that:

```
>>> a = ['aaa %s', 'bbb %s']
>>> b = ['xxx', 'yyy']
>>> map(lambda x, y: x % y, a, b)
['aaa xxx', 'bbb yyy']
```

Comment: `b` is not list in my case

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that you itterate over your list elements and perform appending at that level. Here is my implementation:

```
cmd = [
    "Message %s",
    "Param %s"
    ]

aList = ["MyMessage","MyParam"]

for i in range(len(cmd)):
    cmd[i] %= aList[i]

print(cmd)

==> ['Message Hello', 'Param MyParam']
```

Comment: Could you please explain this code (in your answer)? You may get more upvotes if you do!

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat he is just iterating list and appending values to string ..as simple as string

Comment: @Pilot Yes, but it is best if he explains that in his answer.